Document Node is null when loading multiple models into the viewer, then pixel compare won't work
Since the forge viewer Version 7.90.0 we are struggling with the pixel compare extensions because we get the following error:
TypeError: can't access property "getRootNode", this.secondaryModel.getDocumentNode() is null
Apparently the document node is never set, but we don't know why. If we load a single model, then the document node is set. Also, if we use the forge version 7.89.0 or lower, we do not have the problem with the pixel compare extension.
How can we set the document node properly when loading multiple models? Or is there another option to get the pixel compare extension working without having the document node set?

Could you provide a project to reproduce the issue? Perhaps modify this one that I used for testing? https://github.com/adamenagy/Container/blob/master/PixelCompareIssue790.zip

I was trying to reproduce but it seems a bit tricky. Probably I should also add the we load two models into the extensions which are loaded from autodesk and not locally via a forgeUrn. Also in our case we use the tool to compare 2D .dwg Files. If I try to use the exmaple of you with the .dwg Files it says that they do not support them, so I could not reproduce it with our files.

Are you loading them from ACC? Does it depend on what format you are translating the DWG to? - now we have option to use F2D or PDF: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/advanced-option-rvtdwg-2d-views-svf2-post-job

What does ACC mean? And don't think (or hope) that the format has an influence. We have no problems showing our .DWG Files. It only happens when we use the pixel compare extension. I'm trying though to make a reproducible repo

I tried to make something reproducible but then I get some other error messages, maybe you can have a look into that. But this repo shows basically how we do it currently. https://github.com/Mudo121Bbc/forgeViewerIssuePixelCompare
Can you do something with this? Sry that I can not make something better here

Created PR with my changes including the DWG I used for testing and all seems fine: https://github.com/Mudo121Bbc/forgeViewerIssuePixelCompare/pull/1

Alright thanks, guess I have to do some more investigations in our code base then. I'll keep you updated. Thanks already for your effort!

It seems like I found the Problem after some digging and trying, we were loading the Model with the Function viewer.loadModel(...) but for 2D DWG we have to load it now viewer.loadDocumentNode(...). Interesting, that this did work in the Version 7.89 and lower but not anymore since 7.90. Thanks for all the help!
